# Make TextInputEditText readonly but clickable

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a form in which I have TextInputEditText, I want that it should show a timepicker on clicking it but user should not be able to enter any text directly into that box. I am not replacing this with a TextView or a Button because the form has outlined boxes similar to the screenshot. I want to maintain the uniformity of fields in the form.

[image]

This is the code for the EditText --

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/edittext_add_name"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/min_height"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_import"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_child_care_24">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_add_name_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I have tried `enabled=false` but then the field is not clickable also. Any recommendation how can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Try enabled=false and clickable=true

Comment: Did you try `android:inputType="date"` ?

Comment: this will open keyboard for typing number and he wants to open dialog for date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this code will help you out in the desired output i have done same thing many times.

1st thing do the changes in layout

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/edittext_add_name"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
    android:paddingStart="6dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
         />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

In Java side do this changes to achieve the output

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Calendar myCalendar;
TextInputEditText edt ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    edt = findViewById(R.id.edt);

    myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();


    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener = (datePicker, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) -> {
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateEdtTextview();
    };



    edt.setOnClickListener(view -> new DatePickerDialog(
            TestActivity.this,
            dateListener,
            myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show());

}

private void updateEdtTextview() {
    String myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
    edt.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use this in TextInputEditText:
`android:focusable="false" android:longClickable="false"`